# ShipStation API: How to set/update SKU value for an Order InternationOptions' CustomItem

Tags: json, api, rest, https, e-commerce

How to set SKU value of an [International Options'](https://www.shipstation.com/docs/api/models/international-options/) [Customs Item](https://www.shipstation.com/docs/api/models/customs-item/) using ShipStation API's [Create/Update Order](https://www.shipstation.com/docs/api/orders/create-update-order/) call for an existing [Order](https://www.shipstation.com/docs/api/models/order/)? (`OrderKey` is known and is set during initial order creation. `Customs Declarations` ShipStation account's setting is set to `Create declarations from order items`.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The subject "puzzle" is solved:

- with `Customs Declarations` ShipStation account's setting set to `Create declarations from order items`...

[image]

- ... create product using [Update a Product](https://www.shipstation.com/docs/api/products/update/) ShipStation API call specifying [Product Model's](https://www.shipstation.com/docs/api/models/product/)`customsTariffNo` field value together with other fields' values: `sku`, `name` and `price`. You can also set optional fields' values `customsDescription`, `customsValue`, `customsTariffNo` and `customsCountryCode`. (Note that API's end-point URL should be https://ssapi.shipstation.com/products/createproduct);
- create order using [Create/Update Order](https://www.shipstation.com/docs/api/orders/create-update-order/) ShipStation's API call;
- for the international shipping destination country the customs declaration will be created automatically with properly set `Description`, `SKU`, `Harmonization` etc. fields' values: AFAIU ShipStation API uses `SKU` field value to get the customs forms fields values from the corresponding (by SKU) product definition.